# Three of a kind and a pair on hands bigger than 5

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Given a standard deck and a random $n$-cards hand the probability of having two of one rank and three of another is given by:

for $n=5$:
$$ \frac{{13 \choose 1} {4 \choose 3} {12 \choose 1} {4 \choose 2} }{{52 \choose 5}}$$

(*In words*, I choose one rank, for which there are 13 ways, then there are 4 ways to get three of a kind in this rank. Next choose any of the remaining ranks and count the ways you can get a pair in that rank ${4 \choose 2}$. Finally divide by the total number of possible hands.)

But what about $n=15$?

Using similiar (naive) logic, just adding that the 10 extra cards can be any combination of the remaining 47, I get a non-sensical value: 
$$ \frac{{13 \choose 1} {4 \choose 3} {12 \choose 1} {4 \choose 2} {47 \choose 10}}{{52 \choose 15}} > 1$$

My own simulation shows the actual answer is in the neighbourhood of $0.66$.

What is the failed step I have taken?

*EDIT1*: corrected a typo in the denominator $49 \choose 10$ to $47 \choose 10$...

Comment: What do you mean by having two cards of one rank and three of another in the situation of having fifteen cards?  Must all of the remaining cards all be of different ranks, or can you have multiple ranks where two cards appear and/or multiple ranks where three cards appear, or even some ranks where all four cards appear?

Comment: The remaining cards can be anything... have 4 cards of 3 ranks and 3 of the  4th.

Comment: One possible interpretation of your question is that within the $n$ cards you dealt, there is some subset of five cards such that those five cards form a full house (*as usually defined*).  For example, with $n=6$ not only would $(A\spadesuit~A\heartsuit~A\clubsuit~2\spadesuit~2\heartsuit~3\clubsuit)$ count, but so too would $(A\spadesuit~A\heartsuit~A\clubsuit~2\spadesuit~2\heartsuit~2\clubsuit)$.  The calculation for $n=6$ would be $\frac{13\cdot \binom{4}{3}\cdot 12\cdot \binom{4}{2}\cdot 11\cdot 4 + \binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{3}^2}{\binom{52}{6}}$, seen by breaking into cases on # of triples.

Comment: Using this method to extend to higher $n$ will be incredibly tedious, breaking into cases based on the number of quadruples and the number of triples in the hand etc...  It would probably be easier to count the number of hands which *don't* have a full house as a subset as those can be made only with pairs and singletons.  For $n=15$ one has $1-\frac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}^2\binom{11}{11}4^{11}+\binom{13}{3}\binom{4}{2}^3\binom{10}{9}4^9+\dots+\binom{13}{7}\binom{4}{2}^7\binom{7}{1}4^1}{\binom{52}{15}}$

Answer (score 3):

You have overcounted hands with multiple pairs and three of a kinds,  besides that the last factor in your logic should be $47 \choose 10$.  If you think of a hand with two three of a kinds and two pairs plus five other cards, you could take either three of a kind to be the one you count and also either pair, so you will count this hand four times.  You have also counted cases where there are four of a kind four times for the three of a kind.

Answer (score 0):

To have *exactly* three of a kind once and a pair once with $n=15$, you need to pick the rank that has three of a kind, the rank that has two of a kind, the ranks that occur once, and then assign suits:
$$ \frac{{13\choose 1}{4\choose 3}{12\choose 1}{4\choose 2}{10\choose 9}4^9}{52\choose 15}=\frac{9814671360}{4481381406320}\approx 0.0022.$$

---

To have *at least* one rank that occurs with *at least* three cards and *at least* one other rank that occurs with *at least*  two cards, we would instead first determine the complement: To have at most one multiple rank, or two multiple ranks that are bot pairs.

a) only one multiple rank, this being three-of-a-kind:
$$ \frac{{13\choose 1}{4\choose 3}{12\choose 12}4^{12}}{{52\choose 15}}=\frac{872415232}{4481381406320}$$
b) only one multiple rank, this being four-of-a-kind:
$$ \frac{{13\choose 1}{4\choose 4}{12\choose 11}4^{11}}{{52\choose 15}}=\frac{654311424}{4481381406320}$$
c) two pairs (and nothing else):
$$ \frac{{13\choose 2}{4\choose 2}^2{11\choose 11}4^{11}}{{52\choose 15}}=\frac{11777605632}{4481381406320}$$
Thus the final answer is 
$$1-\frac{872415232+654311424+11777605632}{4481381406320}\approx 0.997 $$

---

Possibly ither interpretations are possible, but their results are presumably somewhere between the above numbers ...